# How to implement a geo route fence

Tags: mongodb, google-maps

Say I keep getting a set of Geo coordinates from a moving vehicle.
There is a predefined route that the vehicle needs to follow from Point A to Point B. 
The route will be defined by giving the user the option to select points A and B and also selecting the WayPoints in between and letting the Google API select the best route. 
As the vehicle moves I need to check whether the vehicle has deviated more than 50 m from the predefined route.

> **My solution (not fully tested)**

When the user has selected the start and the end points and the waypoints in between, I can make a call to the Google Directions API which would give me all the points on the road in between

*(The polyline property inside the steps gives you the exact points on the road which the UI uses to draw the lines. You can call the following URL to see the polyline response 

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA
)*

and store these points in some database (Mongo) with a route id.

When I get the geo cordinates from the vehicle I can make a query to Mongo asking for all those points with the route id and whose distance is less than 50m from the vehicle coordinates. And if there are non then the vehicle has deviated from the route.

Is there a better way of doing this?